# PHP page won't load by JS, with another php file included

Tags: javascript, php, include

In my start.php page I load with JS a file into the header, menu-left and footer div with this code:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("/coach/coach-header.php"); 
  $("#menu-left").load("/coach/team/team-menu-left.php"); 
  $("#footer").load("/coach/coach-footer.html"); 
});
```

This works well as long as the loaded php files doesn't have an included php file in itself. When either coach-header.php or team-menu-left.php have:

```html
<?php 
include '/php/coach-functions.php';
?>
```

they don't load, but without it they do.

What can I do when start.php and the loaded .php files all needs to include coach-functions.php and the only place where it works to include it is in start.php, but there I can't get the other php files to get access to the functions and variables in coach-functions.php?

Comment: and are you getting some errors in the logs?

Comment: @Shiva is right, look at the log. are you sure that the include path is valid?

Comment: The only thing I get is "Status Code:404 Not Found"

Comment: @OriPrice, I'm sure. Because I keep the include path the same. When I take away the inlcude from header.php and paste it into start.php it works in start.php and header.php loads. Only thing is that then header.php can't access the included php file.

Comment: are header.php and start.php in the same folder?

Comment: @OriPrice. No, they are not. Do they need to be?

Comment: Why don't you just include those files on the server side?

Comment: @Luke. I changed to load/include the header and navigation using php, as you suggested. Worked! Don't know why I didn't do this earlier. Thank you!